# IIS 7 MVC App Login Failed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-7

I've build an MVC 5 web application which works perfectly locally. I've uploaded to web server and placed in inetpub folder etc.

This web server uses IIS 7 which I don't have much experience of, however,  I've created a site and app pool as per usual.

When I browse to my site, the homepage loads fine. But once I attempt to login, I am presented with this error

> Cannot open database "StarNewV2" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\StarAppPool'.

This is strange. The database is setup correctly in SQL Server as too is the database user. This info is also in the connection string (Entity Framework) within the app's web.config.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is my connection string in web.config

```
<add name="Star" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*****\*****;initial catalog=myDB;integrated security=True;User ID=myDBUser;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local dev env runs under your credentials, whereas production server uses own AppPool credentials. You need to add DB user for your application and change connect string to login under user credentials.

Check you web.config for **user id=USER;password=PWD**

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=devd;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True; **user id=USER;password=PWD**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

You can also change AppPool Identity to LocalSystem, this will probably solve your issue, but this adds vulnurability to your IIS.

Comment: I've already added a database user within SQL Server on the live server and these credentials are reflected in my web.config. I don't like the idea of doing something that adds vulnerability.

Comment: Can you show you connect string (repolace User \ password with XXX) ?

Comment: By the way? is yor IIS using DB, say for session storage?

Comment: No, my application is not doing that.

Comment: integrated security=True - can you remove this ?

Comment: @fly_us That seems to have done the trick. For further info, `Integrated Security = True` ignores User Id and Password if provided and uses those of the running process. Thanks.